# WPF Storyboard Error

Tags: wpf

I have defind the storyboard in the resources of window. butt when i access this storyboad in the code behind file the follwing error occure

" 'this' name cannot be found in the name scope of  MainWindow"

my code is

```
     Storyboard sb = this.Resources["transferToBasketStoryboard"] as Storyboard
    sb.Begin();
```

can any one help me??

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you created this Storyboard on your `window.resources` scope so the MainWindow.Xaml should begin with :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns: ..... 
    x:Class="myWpfApplication.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>// the resource should be here
    <Storyboard x:Key="transferToBasketStoryboard">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBlock">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="60"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: I have done in the same way, I created two storyboard instances.first i accessed, while accessing the second creating problem.

Comment: i've created two storyboards & two instances no problem its working just fine